# How to get the published timestamp of a page or component using SDL Tridion TOM.NET API

Tags: tridion

I'm trying to get hold of the published timestamp for a given page or component to a given target using the TOM.NET API.   It isn't immediately obvious under the `Page` or `Component` object, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you explain when you are trying to access this information? Is it when the Page or Component is rendered, or at some later point after the publishing has occurred? Do you also need to know this info for a specific target?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `PublishEngine.GetPublishInfo(IdentifiableObject)` method for that, it returns a collection of `PublishInfo` objects which holds the dates and other (publish) information available for the given item.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Bart's answer above, I've knocked up the following rough code.  It's not about performance as this is a proof of concept to demo something to a customer:

```
// if we are in publishing mode, figure out the target we are publishing to, and get the timestamp that the page is published to this target
if (engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget != null)
{
  ICollection<PublishInfo> publishCollections = PublishEngine.GetPublishInfo(childPage);
  foreach (PublishInfo publishInfo in publishCollections)
  {
     if (publishInfo.PublicationTarget == engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget)
     {
        pageElem.SetAttribute("timestamp", publishInfo.PublishedAt.ToString());
     }
   }
}
```

Here you can see I already have my `childPage` object, and i'm adding the result to an existing page XML object (`pageElem.SetAttribute("timestamp", publishInfo.PublishedAt.ToString())`) - so if using this snippet look out for these items :)