# Need to get the XML of a component's that version which is published

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are iterating the components in a folder in Tridion 2011 and creating our custom XML to be used on CDS on the basis of the publishing status of component. I am giving below example to make you understand the problem.

1. Supppose we have 10 components in a folder which are all published and we publish our XML  then the XML gets generated for 10 items.
2. Now we make change in one of the component and don't publish it.
3. After modification of component, we publish the XML again. then the XML get updated for the modified component also. So it creates the difference between the published version of that component and the that is in our XML.

So I want to publish the custom XML in such a way that it should only contain that data which is in sync with published version of component.

Comment: >> "I want to publish the custom XML in such a way that it should only contain that data which is in sync with published version of component" - Are you saying you want to disable updates of content?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, what publishing model are you using? if your content goes into the Dynamic Content Broker, you can get the published content out of the Broker, rather than trying to get it from the Content Manager. For that you can use the Broker API or even the oData webservice (if installed).

Comment: I want to determine the XML of component that was last published and create XML with help of that. I dont need to take care changes which are not yet published.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to:

1. determine the XML of the Component that was last published
2. determine the changes between that XML and the current XML of the Component
3. only publish the changes

Tridion doesn't keep track of the version that was published (on the Content Manager at least). So the closest you can do is find out ***when*** the Component was last published and retrieve the XML of that time. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092156/how-to-get-the-published-timestamp-of-a-page-or-component-using-sdl-tridion-tom) is a great starting point for more information on that approach. Based on that XML you can then do steps 2 and 3 above.

Alternatively you can keep a snapshot of the XML that you published "somewhere" (for example in Application Data) when you're rendering the Component. Then when the Component gets published next time, you can retrieve that XML and do steps 2 and 3 above.

Note that with any of those solutions you should really wonder if you should be implementing it to begin with. You are overriding some of Tridion's default rendering behavior and circumventing part of its architecture (a clear, explicit disconnect between Content Management and Content Delivery, with the former knowing "nothing" about the latter) and anything you do will come back to haunt you in time. In this use-case you have to wonder what will happen when the CDS and TCM get out of sync. Simply republishing the content suddenly won't be good enough anymore, since your code will be in there deciding that "nothing changed since last publish, so we'll publish nothing".

Comment: Point 1 is my exact requirement. I want to do it on CMS part.

Comment: Tridion doesn't have a ready-made: `item.ContentAsLastPublishedToTarget(targetId)` method. So instead I gave you two possible approaches on how to determine this XML: look it up by the LastPublished timestamp or store a snapshot during publishing.

Answer (score 2):

Please forgive me if I jump to conclusions, but I strongly feel this question has arisen from a lack of understanding of Tridion. Publishing in Tridion does more than just raise a flag to indicate the item is 'published', in other words ready to be shown to the outside world. I know this is how some (many) content management systems operate (which may explain why you are asking this question).
In Tridion, however, publishing means that the item is actually - physically - transferred from the content management environment to the content delivery environment. This environment always contains versions of your content that represent the state when the item was last published - simply because it was the very act of publishing that created them.

In my opinion, what you are really asking is how to rebuild this publishing functionality. This is never a good idea. Instead, you should take Bart's comment seriously and look at one of the content delivery APIs that Tridion has on offer (the broker API or the OData web service). Optionally you might want to look into DD4T, which is built on top of the broker and exposes the full Tridion data model.

Comment: We are using eventing for auto publishing of xml. As soon as any of the component get published we publish the xml to CDS automatically itereating over the components in the folder. According to you, we should use broker API and integrate this with eventing. Is my understanding right???

Comment: That would be a far more fruitful approach, yes. Why not profit from proven functionality instead of building it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Then your solution is to

1. Write an event handler on the Publish Transaction Save event
2. Which saves the publish info (version data) to Application Data of the published Component

I'm mentioning the Publish Transaction Save event because from there you can ensure that the publish info is only saved when the transaction is successfull.

Also be aware that this publish info can go out of sync when the event handler fails to execute, and you might loose all of the application data when moving to another environment.

So when this information is absolutely crucial I would save it to a separate database, and not to Application Data.

Comment: Application Data is stored in the CMS database and in Content Porter 2009 SP2 it will also be ported, so depending on how the different environments are being synced, it should be possible to keep the application data there too. But I'm still wondering if this should be implemented on the CM side, from the information gathered this sounds more like a CD side requirement as Frank also indicates in his last paragraph.

Comment: I dont't think this is a CD side requirement. He probably wants to publish a list of some sort, and include only the version of components that have been published as part embedded on a page. But with questions like these with limited background it is hard to figure out what exactly the purpose is. :(